# How to clear an ASP.NET datagrid?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

how do i clear the contents of a data grid that's bound to an list of generic objects?

```
private void BindGrid(ReportWizardCriteria criteria)
{

    gvCriteria.DataSource = criteria.CriteriaList;
    gvCriteria.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
gvCriteria.DataSource = null;
gvCriteria.DataBind();
```

Or you can bind it to an empty collection as well, similar to this

```
gvCriteria.DataSource = new List<MyObject>();
gvCriteria.DataBind();
```

For some people the second one is a bit "easier" to understand

Answer (score 1):

You can set the .DataSource property to null.  That ought to do it.

```
gvCriteria.DataSource = null;
gvCriteria.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

try,

> gvCriteria.Items.Clear();

or,

> gvCriteria.DataSource = null;
>
> gvCriteria.DataBind();